# Javascript error: window.parent.frames[0].getElementById - works fine on first load then fail

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that has multiple iframes in it:

parent

|**__**_iframe1

|**__**_iframe2

|**__**_iframe3

iframe1 has a form with some hidden values. I need ( at least ) one of those values on iframe2

Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(parent.frames[0].document.getElementById("UserID").value);
</script>
```

The first time the site loads, this page works fine. I get my testing popup.  iframe1 is a bunch of tabs that reload iframe2.  When the user ends up navigating back to the tab that includes my script I get a null reference for parent.frames[0].

I'm pulling my hair out trying to fix this and would appreciate any assistance.

I can get this to replicate 100% of the time in Firefox & IE.  With Chrome & Safari it's less so.  Not in that the value is null less often, but MORE often than not the information is not accessible and I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Edit for ease of visibility: These frames are ALL on the same domain, same protocol & port.

While I AM implementing the use of easyXDM so that I can pass some data to another site, I have this issue if I include easyXDM or not.

Thanks!

It looks like it's due to the onLoad as suggested by ddr2.  If you post this as an answer I'll be happy to flag it as the proper one.

I'm kinda bummed I didn't think of that :(

Comment: you should try using the load event. That way you will be sure the frame content is loaded before trying to access it.

Comment: The javascript is at the bottom of the page, so the entire frame should be loaded at this point.  It's only "frame2" that changes content as tabs are clicked, which is the reason that I didn't use the onload event, but I'll give that a try.

Comment: Yes, they are on the same domain, using the same protocol & port.

As a side note, I am implementing easyXDM to do some cross-site scripting, and this is a value I need to pass to another domain. I have that working ( when I can actually get that value from the same domain ).